# Is this statement about product topology correct?

Tags: general-topology

Let $I\ $ be a set of indices. Also let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^I$ be compact in the sense of product topology. Assume $x\in\mathbb{R}^I\ $and $x\notin\Omega.$

Then there exist a finite subset of indices $J\subset I$, such that the corresponding projection operator $P_J$ satisfies $P_J(x)\notin P_J(\Omega)$.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is compact, then it is closed in $\mathbb R ^I$. Does that help?

Comment: I don't think $\mathbb{R}^I$ is always a metric space...

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is metric or not. Think about a product basic open set containing $x$ missing $\Omega$...

Comment: $\Omega$ is closed only if  $\mathbb{R}^I\ $ Hausdoff...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\Omega$ is compact in $\mathbb R ^I$ and $x\in \mathbb R ^I \setminus \Omega$. Then $\Omega$ is closed in $\mathbb R ^I$. So its complement is open. So there is a basic product open set containing $x$, missing $\Omega$. That is, there is a finite $J\subseteq I$ and open sets $U_i$, $i\in I$, such that $x\in \prod _{i\in I} U_i\subseteq \mathbb R ^I \setminus \Omega$, where $U_i=\mathbb R $ if $i\notin J$. Note that $P_J (x)\in \prod _{j\in J} U_j$ and $P_J (y)\notin \prod _{j\in J} U_j$ for all $y\in \Omega$. Therefore $P_J (x)\notin P_J(\Omega)$.